# Hard copy travel guides with information on Tohoku post-tsunami

Tags: japan, guidebooks, tohoku

The 12th edition of Lonely Planet Japan entirely removed Iwate, Miyagi and Fukushima prefectures. I ended up bringing the 11th edition (pre-earthquake) with me when visiting Japan.

Are there hard copy English-language travel guides (either about Japan in general, or Tohoku in particular) that have information on these prefectures, that were written or updated after the Tohoku earthquake and tsunami?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lonely Planet Japan 13th edition will be published in September 2013, and the chapter covering Iwate, Miyagi and Fukushima is [already available online as a free download](http://media.lonelyplanet.com/shop/pdfs/21-northern-honshu-tohoku-jap13.pdf) -- print it out, and you'll have your missing chapter back.

(Disclaimer: I used to work for Lonely Planet.)